# setup constraint in a ConstraintLayout properly while using Guideline

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have following `ConstraintLayout` :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/contact_selector"
    android:minHeight="64dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/image_text"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/contact_circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:text="A.R" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxWidth="248dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image"
        tools:text="Ali Rezaei" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/contact_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="+989121895634" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="Mobile" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        style="@style/LineStyle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can find, `contact_name` is a TextView to right of `image` and top of `guideline`. Text of name can be too long therefore we have :

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
android:maxWidth="248dp"
```

but setting `maxWidth` seems like a bad solution since device can be in landscape orientation.

What is your suggested approach to avoid conflicting between `contact_name` and `phone_type` TextView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can constrain the end of the `@id/contact_name` to the start of the `@id/phone_type` and then set the horizontal bias to `0` to keep it aligned to the left and set `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` so the constraints are enforced when the text gets too long. Your `TextView` for `@id/contact_name` should look like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/phone_type"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image"
    tools:text="Ali Rezaei" />
```

Another way would be to put these two `Views` in a horizontal chain and use `spread_inside` style for it and `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` for the `@id/contact_name` as well.

Comment: `app:layout_constrainedWidth` this attribute can not be found.

Comment: You are probably using the old version of `ConstraintLayout` then. This attribute was added in `1.1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your `contact_name` textview **0dp** in width and set it's *end constraint to the start* of your `phone_type` textview and remove `maxWidth` attribute.

Check this updated layout :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/detail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/contact_selector"
android:minHeight="64dp">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_text"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/contact_circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="A.R" />

</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/phone_type"
    tools:text="Ali Rezaei asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone_number"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/contact_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    tools:text="+989121895634" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    tools:text="Mobile" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    style="@style/LineStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Let me know if it works !

Comment: There is a problem with your solution : arabic words shown in the Right side.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. constraint contact_name on basis of phone_type.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/detail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/contact_selector"
android:minHeight="64dp">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_text"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/contact_circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="A.R" />

</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image"
    tools:text="Mobile" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:maxWidth="248dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/phone_type"
    tools:text="really long long long long long long long long long long name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/contact_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    tools:text="+989121895634" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />



<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    style="@style/LineStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image" />
```

Note - you can also replace frame layout with constraint layout.

Comment: Thanks for your help. +1.

Comment: There is a problem with your solution : arabic words shown in the Right side.